# Is there a way to remove almost duplicated columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr, duplicates

Is there a method in dplyr to remove columns that are almost duplicated?  For example, I would like to remove columns that are greater than 75% duplicated in the following tibble. That would remove column b and c but not column d because it is only 60% identical to any other column.

```
tibble(
       a = c(1,2,3,4,5),
       b = c(1,2,3,4,5),
       c = c(1,2,3,4,4),
       d = c(1,2,3,6,6)
)
```

Comment: You should clarify what is your concept for 'almost duplicated'. When two columns are similar, which should be removed?

Comment: Good question.  I want it to remove one of the redundant columns.  By almost duplicated I meant a large percentage of equivalent cases across rows.  So for example, [3,3] is equivalent to [4,3], but [4,3] is not equivalent to [4,4].  If this was all of the data, there would be a 50% match.  I basically want to specify that > n% match should be identified so that one of those columns could be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is best done not in `dplyr`, to be honest. Many of these functions could be replaced with `purrr`/`tidyr`-variants, but I don't think that there is as easy/efficient a way within `dplyr`.

```r
Z <- tibble(
       a = c(1,2,3,4,5),
       b = c(1,2,3,4,5),
       c = c(1,2,3,4,4),
       d = c(1,2,3,6,6)
)
eg <- expand.grid(seq_len(ncol(Z)), seq_len(ncol(Z)))
eg <- eg[ eg$Var1 < eg$Var2, ]
eg
#    Var1 Var2
# 5     1    2
# 9     1    3
# 10    2    3
# 13    1    4
# 14    2    4
# 15    3    4
eg$similarity <- mapply(function(i,j) sum(Z[,i] == Z[,j]) / nrow(Z), eg$Var1, eg$Var2)
eg
#    Var1 Var2 similarity
# 5     1    2        1.0
# 9     1    3        0.8
# 10    2    3        0.8
# 13    1    4        0.6
# 14    2    4        0.6
# 15    3    4        0.6
unique(eg$Var2[ eg$similarity >= 0.75 ])
# [1] 2 3
```

```r
Z[, -unique(eg$Var2[ eg$similarity >= 0.75 ]) ]
# # A tibble: 5 x 2
#       a     d
#   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     1
# 2     2     2
# 3     3     3
# 4     4     6
# 5     5     6
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to calculate how similar different columns are to each other. You can then examine this and decide what columns to throw out.

```r
num_cols = ncol(my_data)

similarity_matrix = matrix(nrow = num_cols, ncol = num_cols)

for(ii in 1:num_cols){
  col1_name = colnames(my_data)[ii]
  for(jj in 1:num_cols){
      col2_name = colnames(my_data)[jj]

    calc = my_data %>%
        ungroup() %>%
        mutate(diff = ifelse(!!sym(col1_name) == !!sym(col2_name), 1, 0)) %>%
        summarise(num_diffs = sum(diff))

    similarity_matrix[ii,jj] = calc / num_cols
  }
}
```

Then the `ii,jj`-th entry of `similarity_matrix` will tell you the proportion of entries that are the same in the `ii`-th and `jj`-th columns.

Note that `!!sym(col1_name)` is the dplyr way to take text that contains the name of a column and use it in code as the column name:

```r
select(df, my_favourite_column)
```

Is equivalent to:

```r
column_text = "my_favourite_column"
select(df, !!sym(column_text))
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Am I supposed to replace anything other than my_data in your syntax with the tibble I included?  When I tried the above tibble in place of my_data it gave me the error...numerical expression has 4 elements: only the first usedError in 1:foo : NA/NaN argument.  I apologize if I did something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This function is fairly efficient and actionable. The function returns a logical vector of columns to drop. It requires that all columns are numeric.

Because 'identical' is a loose term, I used the `stringdist` package, which has functions for comparing the similarity of strings and numeric vectors. You can customize which algorithm you use, depending on what your goals are.

#### Example

```r
# Which columns are similar with a cutoff of 0.7?
similar_columns(df, 0.7)
## [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE

# Remove only exactly identical columns
df[, !similar_columns(df, 1)]

#       c     d
#   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     1
# 2     2     2
# 3     3     3
# 4     4     6
# 5     4     6
```

#### Function

```r
# Get stringdist package if you don't already have it
if (!require(stringdist)) {
    install.packages('stringdist')
    library(stringdist)
}

# --------------

similar_columns <- function(df, cutoff) {

  # function for determining similarity of columns
  nearly_identical <- function(df, cola, colb, cutoff) {
    if (stringdist::seq_sim(list(df[[cola]]), list(df[[colb]])) >= cutoff) return(TRUE)
    else return(FALSE)
  }
  
  # generate a similarity matrix
  sim_matrix <- matrix(nrow = ncol(df), ncol = ncol(df))
  for (i in 1:ncol(df)) {
    for (j in 1:ncol(df)) {
      sim_matrix[i, j] = nearly_identical(df, names(df)[i], names(df)[j], cutoff)
    }
  }
  
  # Vector of columns to drop
  col_drop <- vector(length = ncol(df))
  for (i in seq_len(ncol(df))) {
    if (sum(sim_matrix[i, ], na.rm = TRUE) > 1) col_drop[i] <- TRUE
    
    else col_drop[i] <- FALSE
  }
  return(col_drop)
}
```

The cutoff changes depending on the algorithm you use, the default is on a zero to 1 scale (1 being totally identical). With a cutoff of 0.7, columns `a`, `b`, and `c` should be dropped because they have at least one nearly identical column.